# Another "real vs virtual particle" one: calculate the full diagram or $\sigma \times \mathrm{BR}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, scattering-cross-section, virtual-particles

I have recently been forced to think about something I always thought that I understood but that, in reality, I could not be more confused about.

Suppose I want to study the LHC prospects for observation of the process $pp \to   e^+ e^-\nu_e \bar{\nu}_e$. There could be two ways to go about it:

(*i*) One could evaluate the complete diagram, at fourth power of electroweak strength and two virtual $s$-channel $W$ bosons, *i.e.*, $pp  \to W^{+*} W^{-*} \to (e^+ \nu_e) (e^- \bar{\nu}_e)$ -- the $W$ pair comes from exchange of a $s$-channel boson or $t$-channel fermion. From this amplitude, the corresponding $2 \to 4$ cross section may be directly evaluated and analysed.

(*ii*) Another option is evaluating the cross section for the process $p p \to WW$. The result to be, for instance, plotted would then be this production cross section times the relevant branching ratio $\sigma(p p \to WW)\times\mathrm{BR}(W^+\to\nu e^+)^2$.

Some of the differences between the use of each possibility are obvious. For instance, (*i*) allows for interference effects to be taken into consideration and has a larger phase space available; while (*ii*) appears to assume that the $W$ decay occurs at prompt collider scale (in this specific phenomenological effort).

I say that I always thought to understand this, and my previous impression was that evaluating the full diagram is always the correct approach, while (*ii*) relies on the Narrow Width Approximation, in which case both results should be similar up to corrections in $\Gamma/M$.

However, only now I stopped to think about the huge amount of papers which specifically treat each approach as appropriate to *distinct* physical possibilities. For instance, some works would compare the benefits of considering one $W$ boson real and one virtual instead of just evaluating the full diagram. Additionally, experimental works tend to use method (*ii*) when casting data in the form of a prediction of some model.

To make matters worse, I have run a few tests on analogous processes and always obtain a final cross section using method (*ii*) that is between $1.6$ to $2$ times larger than the one obtained through method (*i*), which hardly seems to be a good approximation.

So, what am I missing? When are these things different and when one or the other should be utilized?

**Edit**: My calculations were wrong -- the cross section for method (*i*) is in general larger. The bulk of the question remains, though.

Comment: There are some considerations about the narrow-width approximations that might interest you given here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.06823 and also here: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0703058

Comment: This question could possibly be answered using pretty basic QFT reasoning, *plus* some concrete examples of what you're talking about (i.e. links to specific papers).